# Display a list of matching lines from multiple files in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a plugin which will work in the same way as grep, but display the results in a temporary window like :spell does for suggestions?

So, 
:grep 'foo' /foo/bar/*/* 
But displaying the list of matching lines in a temporary window as a reference rather than to be edited?

Comment: Also, could this be done in the same manner as the [Visual Search function](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip171)? Highlight text to be searched for in visual mode, then search through the project and display with quickfix? @lucapette

Answer (score 2):

After grepping with `:grep 'foo' /foo/bar/` just issue the `:copen` command. This will open the quickfix window. After you are done you can close it easily with `:cclose`.

You can move through the list with `:cnext` and `:cprev`. I suggest mapping these to make it easier. I use Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin with provides `[q` and `]q` mappings to move though the quickfix list.

For more help

```
:h cope
:h ccl
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim). It runs [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) to search in your project and does exactly what you need using the [quickfix](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix) window . I recommend you to install the latest version of ack if you're going to try it.